# How to run multiple processes on Arduino

Tags: timer, arduino

I'm working with an Arduino for the first time in my life for a school project.
I want to make a coffee reminder alarm, so you don't forget you made a cup of coffee for yourself.

I'm working with an FSR sensor which measures the presence of the coffee cup. When the cup is placed the LED should turn on to show you a timer has started ending with a reminding buzzer.

Right now I'm using a delay, but this isn't working as I want to. Because of the delay you can remove the cup and the timer still goes on with the buzzer at the end.

I want the LED and the timer/buzzer to go off when the cup gets removed midway the process.

I never ever programmed before in my life, and I find it quite hard to get my head around it.

Here's my code:

```cpp
int fsrPin = 0; 
int fsrReading; 
int LEDpin = 11;
const int buzzer = 7;

void setup(void) {
    Serial.begin(9600); 
    pinMode(LEDpin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(void) {
    fsrReading = analogRead(0); 

    Serial.print("Analog reading = ");
    Serial.print(fsrReading); 

    if (fsrReading < 10) {
        Serial.println(" - No Cup");
        digitalWrite(LEDpin, LOW); 
        noTone(buzzer);
    }

    else if (fsrReading > 10) {
        Serial.println(" - Cup pressent");
        digitalWrite(LEDpin, HIGH);
        noTone(buzzer);
        delay(10000);
        tone(buzzer, 700);
        delay(1000);
    }

    delay(500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino library has a `millis()` and a `micros()` functions that you should be able to make use of.  They report the number of milli-seconds  or micro-seconds since boot.

You can set a variable to record what time one thing happened, then later see if the the current millis() is more than say 30,000 (30 seconds) after the previous recorded time.

Adafruit has a nice tutorial on this subject, which can be found [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-1/overview).